# How to create a soomth dashed in Cesium

Tags: smoothing, cesiumjs

I am attempting to draw dashed lines in Cesium using the PolylineDashType feature. However, when I do so, the map becomes blurry and shrinks to a certain level. Are there any alternative methods for drawing smooth dashed lines?